# Prize Money Distribution

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to figure out a prize money distribution where 100% of the money would go to 65 contestants.  The constraint is that each following position drop cannot be greater than a previous drop.  So if 1st place was 100 and second place was 80 third place could be no greater than 60.

Is there a formula that would help solve this?  Something where the integral of the curve through the 65 position would equal 100% and the rate of change would diminish as the finish position worsened?

Answer (score 2):

You want to give $65$ nonnegative awards, $a_1, \ldots, a_{65}$, satisfying $$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{65}=(\text{total prize})$$
and each of the conditions below; $$a_1-a_2\le a_2-a_3,~~ a_2-a_3\le a_3-a_4,~~\ldots,~~ a_{63}-a_{64}\le a_{64}-a_{65}$$